# How to use react j s components in react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Is it possible to use all the reactjs components in react native app?If no,what is the best way to switch between react js and react native?

If an app is done using react js is it necessary(Compulsory) to use redux in that?

Answer (score 9):

There are two main points:

1.The base UI components in React (DOM) and React Native are different.

2.The ‘React’ objects in React and React Native are different (React Native removes the DOM-specific stuff adds a lot of native-specific code).

please check this link for more details:

https://medium.com/@aakashns/sharing-components-between-react-and-react-native-f6ce3713658a#.oa4my8p36

Answer (score 6):

I avoid these types of quests because `React JS` UI components built for the web have different semantics than `React JS` UI components built for `React Native`.

`React Native` doesn't have `<div/>` or `<img/>` or a `DOM` for that matter.

`React Native` uses `React JS` components that bind to native views, and things like `CSS` are so very different than that  from the Web.

The *only* way you'd be able to use a `React JS` UI component in a `React Native` app is by making it 100% of the height and width of an embedded webview.  It's possible (i've done it for testing purposes), but not ideal.

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898552/how-to-reuse-the-react-js-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use all the reactjs components in react native app?

React Native uses other types of components which aren't related to HTML, but to iOS and Android views. Even the styling is [slightly different](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html).

> If no,what is the best way to switch between react js and react native?

You can still reuse other parts of your code. If you use redux, for example, you should keep using almost the same code.

> If an app is done using react js is it necessary(Compulsory) to use redux in that?

No, redux is just an implementation of the [flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). There are others, but redux is the most popular one.

Answer (score 3):

If your component contains pure js logic, then yes. React js is meant for Web, where we make use of web semantic. React native extends mobile native UI components.